# Using mysql statement to join tables and return maximum values instead of PHP maths

Tags: php, mysql, join

In PHP with MySQL I am trying to write queries to pull certain required reports with Joined Tables.I have read though so many SQL scripting manuals, and would normally do this type of thing by pulling filtered records from db tables into PHP, and doing the math gymnastics there. Unfortunately this is inefficient so I am looking for the right SQL query to point me in the right direction. This is my situation.

I have mysql tables: events and payments, they are linked by a single ID column (events.event_id = payments.payment_event_id)

I need to get a recordset containing only the 5 events with the most associated payments. Then I would like a result array containing this original event detail arrays along with an integer which is their ticket payment count.

Ideally the result array structure would look like this:

```
$result_events--
|0||0|payment count(53)
|0||1|$full event array

|1||0|Payment Count (34)
|1||1|$full event array
```

EDIT:

After talking to people I thought I would spell out what I am after. I need a 2 column resultset, left column is event_id (from events table) and right hand column is total amount of payments for that event (ie the number of 'payment' rows which match this event id. So out of huge random tables of events and payments, I would like to be left with one like this:

```
| Event_id | total Payments |
```

but ordered by the payment column. I know I'm asking the earth :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the 5 most common payments for an event and get just those 5 details, you can do a subquery to get the event_ids where you group the payment_event_ids, then order the count descending top to bottom and take the top 5 results.

Then you take those ID's and get the event details that match those ids

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  events 
WHERE 
  event_id IN (
    SELECT 
      payment_event_id 
    FROM 
      payments 
    GROUP BY payment_event_id 
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC 
    LIMIT 5
  );
```

Optionally you can also get all the payment details with a join, but you'll get more than 5 rows returned this way

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  events 
JOIN
  payments
ON
  events.event_id = payments.payment_event_id
WHERE 
  events.event_id IN (
    SELECT 
      payment_event_id 
    FROM 
      payments 
    GROUP BY payment_event_id 
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC 
    LIMIT 5
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple query, only thing left for you to do is select the columnnames you need from both tables:

```
$q = "SELECT events.columname, payments.columnname FROM events
      INNER JOIN payments ON events.event_id = payments.payment_event_id
      ORDER BY payments.payment_count DESC
      LIMIT 5";
```

Comment: Thanks Daan, this almost worked. however it is giving me one line per payment line in the table, and showing the relevant event name next to it. I altered the query slightly to 
SELECT events.event_name, payments.Payment_total_amount FROM events INNER JOIN payments ON events.event_id = payments.payment_event_id ORDER BY payments.payment_id DESC